# saveEventually - Save when application is minimised with Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am using `saveEventually` in the section of code below. The issue is, saveEventually doesn't work when the application is minimised and reopened, only when the application is completely closed and reopened. Is there any way to counteract this?

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
        // Generate Random Number
        int random = arc4random_uniform(1000000000);

        // Updates Location
        NSLog(@"Location: %@",newLocation);
        CLLocation *curentLocation = newLocation;

            if (curentLocation != nil) {

            // Submit through Parse
            PFObject *object = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Issue"];
            object[@"ID"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",random];
            object[@"Latitude"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",curentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
            object[@"Longitude"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",curentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
            object[@"Signal"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_avgNumber];
            [object saveEventually];

            // Update Text Fields
            self.latitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",curentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
            self.longitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",curentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
            self.signal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_avgNumber];

            }

    // Stop the Location Update
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using saveInBackground?

Comment: Yeah, my application is likely to be used offline due to the nature of the information it captures, so saveEventually should prevent data from being lost when offline.

Answer (score 1):

`saveEventually` will work under both of the conditions you described.  From Parse: "Objects saved with this method will be stored locally in an on-disk cache until they can be delivered to Parse.
 **They will be sent immediately if possible**.  Otherwise, they will be sent the next time a network connection is available."

It should work, but as a temporary workaround if it's not, you could check for connectivity before saving the object.  If you have a internet connection, use `saveInBackground`, if not use `saveEventually`.  So something like this:

```
if (isNetworkAvailable)
    [object saveInBackground];
else
    [object saveEventually];

- (BOOL)isNetworkAvailable
{
   CFNetDiagnosticRef dReference;        
   dReference = CFNetDiagnosticCreateWithURL (NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.apple.com"]);

   CFNetDiagnosticStatus status;
   status = CFNetDiagnosticCopyNetworkStatusPassively (dReference, NULL);        

   CFRelease (dReference);

   if ( status == kCFNetDiagnosticConnectionUp )
   {
      NSLog (@"Connection is Available");
      return YES;
   }
   else 
   {
    NSLog (@"Connection is down");
    return NO;
   }
}
```

Comment: In theory you are correct, but in practise the method doesn't perform. As stated, the issue is that the object is not sent when connectivity is re-established once the application has been minimised and reopened.